# How to fix incorrect ajax custom post type displaying on WordPress

Tags: ajax, wordpress

There is a WordPress website. On this project, the output of blog posts and products is implemented using ajax. Here is this page:

Blog page —  [1]: https://tirador.anvi.team/blog/

Product page — [2]: https://tirador.anvi.team/products/

If on the blog page click the download more button new articles displays more and more until all entries are over.

But on the product page, there is different behavior. If you click the download more button new products simply replace those that were.

I have not developed this site and I do not have enough knowledge on ajax for solving this issue. I need new products to appear on the product page in the same way as on the blog page.

Here are links to the code that answers the output of the records. It seems to me.

Load Posts Ajax: https://codeshare.io/GArO9N

```
function more_post_ajax(){
    $pages = get_pages(array(
        'meta_key' => '_wp_page_template',
        'meta_value' => 'tpl-blog.php'
    ));
    foreach($pages as $page){
        $page_id = $page->ID;
    }
$offset = $ppp = get_field('all_blog_posts_count', $page_id);
$page = (isset($_POST['pageNumber'])) ? $_POST['pageNumber'] : 0;
 header("Content-Type: text/html");

$args = array(
    'suppress_filters' => true,
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'posts_per_page' => $ppp,
    'paged'    => $page,
);

$loop = new WP_Query($args);

$out = '';

if ($loop -> have_posts()) :  while ($loop -> have_posts()) : $loop -> the_post();
    $out .= get_template_part('loop/latest-post-item');

    endwhile;
    endif;
    wp_reset_postdata();
    die($out);
}

add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_more_post_ajax', 'more_post_ajax');
add_action('wp_ajax_more_post_ajax', 'more_post_ajax');
```

Load Products Ajax: https://codeshare.io/5NBJrJ

```
 function load_products() {

    $page = (isset($_POST['pageNumber'])) ? $_POST['pageNumber'] : 0;
    $producer_id = (isset($_POST['producer_id'])) ? $_POST['producer_id'] : 0;
    $cats = ( isset( $_POST['categories'] ) ) ? $_POST['categories'] : false;
    $colors = ( isset( $_POST['product_colors'] ) ) ? $_POST['product_colors'] : false;
    $price_range = ( isset( $_POST['price_range'] ) ) ? $_POST['price_range'] : false;

    header("Content-Type: text/html");  

        $args = array(
            'suppress_filters' => true,
            'post_type' => 'products',
            'posts_per_page' => 6,
            'paged'    => $page,

        );


    $loop = new WP_Query($args);

    $out = '';

    if ($loop -> have_posts()) :  while ($loop -> have_posts()) : $loop -> the_post();
         $out .= get_template_part( 'loop/product', 'grid' );

         endwhile;
         endif;
         wp_reset_postdata();
         die($out);
}
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_load_products', 'load_products');
add_action('wp_ajax_load_products', 'load_products');
```

And this is the hole ajax.php file: https://codeshare.io/21QXjB

I can not solve this issue, please help me to find the issue.

Comment: Please post code here, thanks

Comment: I thought it would be more convenient. Therefore, I shared the code through codeshare.io But now I've added the code into the body of the message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `main.js` file find `load_products_all_products_page()` function and change below line:

```
$('.list-products').html($data);
```

With the below one:

```
$('.list-products').append($data);
```

Comment: Wow! For a week I went over the code by bones but still could not find a solution. And you suggested the right solution without even seeing the file main.js. Thank you very much! This is some common code on the Internet that you even knew the name of the function: load_products_all_products_page() ?

Comment: @VictorSokoliuk No, You have provided your URL. So from there, I was able to detect the issue you were facing.